# angular puts slash in index.php#/todiv so icant go todiv

Tags: angularjs

This happens nearly always.

AngularJS puts slash in **index.php#/gohere**, so i can't go to "gohere".

Why angular puts? and how to prevent it from putting slash between index.php#/gohere?
normally it should be like this **index.php#gohere**, doens't it?

**edit:**
now i changed html alittle. it does like this now.
    http://localhost/subsite/#/here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash inside the URL is called "Hashbang Mode".

You can add an option to your app.config() section
that turns off the default hashbang mode and activates
the HTML5-history based mode:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This mode allows you to use URLs without the hash,
e.g.

```
http://localhost/subsite/here
```

instead of

```
 http://localhost/subsite/#/here
```

You can find more information about the modes in the official angular JS documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location
(scroll down to "Hashbang and HTML5 Modes")

Comment: why did they needed to do something like that ?. is there some harming situation